# JS not giving any result(Objects)

Tags: javascript

Please have a look at the following code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Using Javascript</title>
        <meta http-equiv="author" content="infinite_999">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="name"></div>
        <div id="rooms"></div>
        <div id="booked"></div>
        <div id="available"></div>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var hotel={
    //Properties
    name:'Pacific Idea',
    rooms:20,
    booked:15,
    //Methods
    checkAvailability = function () {
        return this.rooms- this.booked;
    }
};

var nameHotel=document.getElementById('name');
var roomHotel=document.getElementById('rooms');
var bookedHotel=document.getElementById('booked');
var availableHotel=document.getElementById('available');

nameHotel.textContent=hotel.name;
roomsHotel.textContent=hotel.rooms;
bookedHotel.textContent=hotel.booked;
availableHotel.textContent=hotel.checkAvailability();
```

Now according to this code, the name, number of booked rooms, number of available rooms of the hotel should be displayed. But unfortunately, it just doesn't display anything.

Please help me..

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: There are two errors (syntax and reference error) in your script - which both will be shown in the console of your developer tools.

Comment: what are those two errors?(I am not using any IDE, just notepad ++)

Comment: [How can I debug my JavaScript Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: @Siddhantinf You doin't need an IDE, use the browser's Javascript console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 errors in your javascript code. one is checkAvailability = function (); should be ':' instead of '='. and roomsHotel typo error.

Try

```
var hotel={
//Properties
name:'Pacific Idea',
rooms:20,
booked:15,
//Methods
checkAvailability : function () {
    return this.rooms- this.booked;
}
};

var nameHotel=document.getElementById('name');  
var roomsHotel=document.getElementById('rooms');
var bookedHotel=document.getElementById('booked');
var availableHotel=document.getElementById('available');

nameHotel.textContent=hotel.name;
roomsHotel.textContent=hotel.rooms;
bookedHotel.textContent=hotel.booked;
availableHotel.textContent=hotel.checkAvailability();
```

Comment: What?? I am using Javascript

Comment: 2 errors in your javascript code. one is checkAvailability = function (); should be ':' instead of '='. and roomsHotel typo error

Comment: Edit your answer and explain what was wrong with the original code and how you fixed it.

Comment: mentioned in previous comment @Barmar

Comment: Put it in the answer, not a comment.

Comment: Thnx @krishna...  I feel stupid about those mistakes